# Facing issue to connect mongodb and mongoexpress using docker?

Tags: mongodb, docker, path

[MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Mongo Express server listening at http://0.0.0.0:8081
Server is open to allow connections from anyone (0.0.0.0)
basicAuth credentials are "admin:pass", it is recommended you change this in your config.js!

[image]

Comment: That is just a warning, was there a problem with the connection?

Comment: it gives me error as Turn on admin in config.js to view server stats!

Comment: this is the link of localhost page image [link of localhost  image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fWajk-XSJNFYgfIhGRCvFK22tohBWVeR/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you looked at config.js and how to turn on admin there?

Comment: I checked config database which is present in web UI [UI Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fWajk-XSJNFYgfIhGRCvFK22tohBWVeR/view) , but I am unable to turn on admin. please help me I am stucking in this issue from last 3 days.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, mongodb-express in docker's latest release doesn't have server status, but 0.54.0 had it.

Try: `docker pull mongo-express:0.54.0`

And then remember to use `mongo-express:0.54.0` for whatever you're doing later.